How to survive 40°C while golfing?
I am an avid golfer in Palm Springs. At this time of year, temperatures often reach 40°C (104°F) or more.
What should/can I do to avoid heat exhaustion or heat stroke (short of going inside to a/c)?

Indeed, restricting outdoor activities to the cooler hours of the day, and then to being (partly) immersed in cool water is the only sensible response to 40°C. (I hear that the Ocean is not always cool enough these days; currently it's 89°F/32°C.) Remedy: Migrate North and join a group that lobbies for a faster transition to a climate friendly economy, the latter more for the sake of any possible children than of yourself.

I've found the best option is to play one hole, announce that it's too hot and then spend the next few hours in the lounge bar regaling people with the story of how you nearly died of heatstroke, and yes, I'll take another drink thanks for offering.

I think Valorum has the best solution!

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Indeed, the thriathlon rules start to seriously throttle down swimming past 31C - people can overheat in too-warm water if they exert themselves

The first thing I would do is to research the signs of heat exhaustion/heat stroke on medical websites.
Sample earch : signs heat exhaustion
Here's such an example at Webmd.

Heat exhaustion is one of three major heat-related illnesses. The other two are heat cramps, which are less serious, and heat stroke, which is the most serious.


Because these conditions can progress from one to another, they are sometimes described as the three stages of heat illness.

Consult a number of them, that should start to give you an idea.  Another is at Heat Stress Related Illness | NIOSH | CDC
For example, @ Webmd:

Some symptoms that could point to heat stroke, rather than heat exhaustion, include:


....



Not being able to sweat


That would put you on the lookout for non-obvious symptoms like "not being able to sweat".  Or the even more counter-intuitive "cool, moist skin with goosebumps".
Familiarize yourself with the symptoms and figure out which ones you plan to be on the lookout for, as well as their sequence.  For example, not sweating is at the (more advanced) heat stroke stage, but the (preceding) heat exhaustion stage lists excessive sweating as a possible symptom. But you could also over-sweat at the heat stroke stage, so, yes, complicated.
Depending on your medical status and age, I would also ask a physician for their advice.  That webmd site outlines a number of causes for special concern.  Check out which ones apply to you.
I would also be cautious about assuming that "staying hydrated" is sufficient.  Past a certain point, your ability to shed heat can become insufficient, with or without hydration.
Stick to medical sites for reference at first, avoid "popular wisdom" sources on the first pass.  A second, more informed pass on what golfers have to recommend might very well be useful, once you know the basic medical information.
Check out weather websites to see if they are fielding any special weather warnings for the day.  They do where I live.
My own first line of defense - but I don't golf - would be to seek out shade as much as possible, a hat and appropriate clothing, along with drinking water:  yes, as per another comment, alcohol and heat are a known risk, I'd hold off till after for my beers :-(
Golf is a social activity.  You might want to go over some of this with your frequent golfing partners, like you would with a scuba diving buddy.  Symptoms like confusion, altered mental status, slurred speech, under heat stroke, are way more noticeable by others than by oneself.  Look out for them and ask them to look out for you.

I would keep an eye out for news items covering golfing heat accidents, esp in one's immediate area (an area with high humidity would be more prone to issues than a dry one).  It's one thing to be careful and proactive if it is an infrequent problem.  It's another if it happens regularly.
Advice about keeping safe from the golf community needs to take into account that some of the professional side of might be incentivized to keep you playing.  While many a manly man will want to talk up their manliness:  "I played in 117, it's no big deal as long as you're fit", was one such Reddit-based jewel.
As per comment:  obviously, one reason for looking up the risks and symptoms is for you to stop and head for cooler climes if you feel at risk.  Think through the decision-making for that process ahead of time, so that you don't get carried away in the "heat of the moment" and try to power through.

It should also be emphasized that your health is more important than your (golf) handicap. Don't be afraid to abandon your game. If you start to show any symptoms, or if you're simply not feeling comfortable with the heat, %$@% the "just one more hole" and head to the air conditioned clubhouse.

Also worth noting that drinking alcohol in extreme heat is probably not recommended...but from what I understand that's like, half of the golfing experience, so YMMV if that advice is taken or not :)

For the gloomily minded, The heat will kill you first is an interesting book covering heat waves and climate change and covers a number of heat stroke/death anecdotes, including the author's own near call.  Things are likely to get worse.

I won't repeat the excellent advice of @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica, above.  (I will reiterate that it might be more satisfying to have a lousy handicap and be alive than an enviable handicap and be dead.)
My remedy for being outside gardening in the heat was to get several neckerchiefs (bandanas) which had pockets with freezable gel caps sewn in.  Keep the bandanas in the freezer when not in use. Transport the bandanas in an insulated tote which has a large freezable gel slab, which gel slab should also be in the freezer when not in use.  Three bandanas might last you three hours, unless you are in sun all the time, which you may be, on a golf course.
I bought my bandanas years ago, and saw nothing exactly like them on Amazon just now, but did not search thoroughly.  Something similar is probably available at a large gardening or sports store.  The insulated tote and the large freezable gel slab was available at my local CVS last year; they are widely used to transport small amounts of food that should be kept cold.  They are a negligble addition to the stuff a golfer transports around the course.
As a handier alternate, anything that provides evaporative cooling around the neck or on the head will help, even just water, although ice is better.  And note that the Bedouin developed clothing for these conditions centuries ago.  You could start a new fashion in golf.
Finally, things are going to get worse with time, not better, despite fluctuations. One cool week does not a reversal of climate change make. So, IMO, it is time to develop habits to deal with heat, such as dawn rising for golf, tennis, gardening, and so on. And, you might lobby for strategically located misting stations at your course.
